# Using Custom Class Renders in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am migrating from Android Studio to Xamarin.Forms, and I have a question regarding custom controls.  I want to have a floating label for my data entry fields for aesthetics reasons.  The custom control I am trying to use is Xfx.Controls.  The site for this control is

https://github.com/XamFormsExtended/Xfx.Controls

The namespace for this custom class is Xfx and the assembly is Xfx.Controls.  On the mainpage xaml file, I am inserting the following line in the ContentPage...

```
"xmlns:xfx="clr-namespace:Xfx;assembly=Xfx.Controls"
```

Now when I add an element to the form

```
<xfx:XfxEntry Placeholder="First Name"/>
```

everything works as expected.  The label floats like it should.  For the next step, I push a new NavigationPage from a button press to navigate to a new page.  Just as on the mainpage, I had

```
"xmlns:xfx="clr-namespace:Xfx;assembly=Xfx.Controls"
```

and added the same XfxEntry control.  Now when I try to compile and run, I get the error message:

```
Failed to resolve assembly:'Xfx.Controls, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToke=null'
```

I would like to know why everything works fine on the mainpage, but fails on all subsequent navigation pages. I appreciate any input!

For the sake of completeness, here are the other namespaces

```
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:xfx="clr-namespace:Xfx;assembly=Xfx.Controls"
xmlns:app="clr-namespace:RaceDay;assembly=RaceDay"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RaceDay"
x:Class="RaceDay.MainPage"
NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="True">
```

Comment: That seems strange and should work. Your pages are in the same assembly right? Could you update your question with the (simplified) pages? Both the working and not working one?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:xfx="clr-namespace:Xfx;assembly=Xfx.Controls"
             xmlns:app="clr-namespace:RaceDay;assembly=RaceDay"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RaceDay"
             x:Class="RaceDay.SecondPage"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="True">

        <xfx:XfxEntry Placeholder="First Name"/>

    </ContentPage>